# Python: regular expressions in url

Tags: python, regex

I have some url like

```
https://www.avito.ru/chelyabinsk/avtomobili/audi_a4_2014_818414044
```

And I need to get pattern from this. I know, that * is the symbol, that can replace any symbol, but when I try `https://www.avito.ru/*/avtomobili` it doesn't open this url. 
How can I fix that?

Comment: Seems you are confusing regular expressions with [fnmatch patterns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fnmatch.html). For regular expressions `*` is a repetition operator that allows you to repeat the *preceding group/character* zero or more times. Depending on your use case you want either `[^/]+` or `.+`.

Comment: Uhm, no, `*` by itself won't do anything, much less "open a URL". We're missing about half the context here, in what situation you're trying to apply `*` to what exactly.

Comment: @deceze I need to parse some data from page content and first I should open url, I have a lot of url like `http://www.avito.ru/chelyabinsk/avtomobili/audi_a4_2014_818414044` but symbol between `www.avito.ru` and `avtomobili` are different and I want to replace this symbols to open all url

Comment: @ArseniyKrupenin It doesn't work that way, the web has no concept of "globbing", i.e. you cannot expand a URL this way. This works only with filenames when you can explicitly list the files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means match the last symbol zero or more times.

For example, `x*` matches 'xxxxxxx....', and `[a-z]*` matches 'abcsiiwdqhwid...'.

Why not try

```
https://www.avito.ru/[a-z]*/avtomobili
```

or

```
https://www.avito.ru/.*?/avtomobili
```

Comment: I try `if 'http://www.avito.ru/.*?/avtomobili' in url:
        print len(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())` but it not returns any url, but some are like `http://www.avito.ru/ryazan/avtomobili?pmax=50000&f=188_893b1397`

Comment: regex is not for this use. It can match patterns in **known** text, but it cant magic up _unknowns_.

Comment: @ScottStainton but what I should use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, to match

```
https://www.avito.ru/chelyabinsk/avtomobili/audi_a4_2014_818414044
```

you would need to have a regex of

```
https://www\.avito\.ru/.*?/avtomobili
```

in `https://www.avito.ru/XXXXXX/avtomobili` : `XXXXXX` can be anything

`.*?` means match anything (as little as possible) until you get to /avtomobili

You also need to escape any DOT like this `\.`

Comment: and if I need to replace this url `http://tyumen.drom.ru/bmw/5-series/15304602.html`, can I write `if 'drom\.ru/.*?/.*?/\d.html' in url:`?

Comment: Can you please be more specific with what you mean with "in url"